# PowerShell comparison operators

Tags: powershell-3.0

PowerShell has a unique set of comparison operators: -eq -gt -lt -ne etc. 
I vaguely remember using such operators in a different language, but can't recollect which one.

Which other languages use such notations? what is reason for not using the standard operators (==, >,<, !=)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unix [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) command for instance uses similar operators. [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) has operators like that too, although without the leading hyphen.

The reason for PowerShell to use mnemnics rather than symbols for the comparison operators is probably that some of the commonly used comparison symbols are already in use for other operations (`=` → assignment, `>` → redirection).